# Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz File has unexpected size (7772 != 7605)

Tags: azure, hash, package, azure-cli

Full error:

Failed to fetch 
[`https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz`](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz)  File has unexpected size (7772 != 7605). Mirror sync in progress?
Has anyone faced this issue for this package?
I wasn't getting any issue till yesterday.
But today all pipelines are failing with this error while trying to download azure-cli

Comment: I think Azure has issues. Getting the same error. You are not alone. :)

Comment: We have similar issues using GitHub Actions which is based on Azure Pipelines as well. Super annoying,

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved. We are not getting this error anymore.
I think the issue was from the Azure side and they have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar issue today in the debian dists.

```
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  File has unexpected size (72896 != 72828). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 40.76.35.62 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:72828 [weak]
    - SHA512:3e2135a607d82f3d0fb22a952998f1306ce456553daedb681bee125507c96d0b6e6429b110c92ae9cef8ae09974c74fbabb4e28aeab32ebed9962d2c61238686
    - SHA256:4217b6ad3a63657ec03df9a3f95c0c5a55401f760790b48269e80dcf6ac19171
    - SHA1:5b709f4947671085a4172e9d90248fef90be7355 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:3564888127c08fa04b2b27e345507089 [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 18:06:13 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: They have updated the package last night, and I think they re-introduced this issue again.